# pgsql string escape when inserting

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am new with PostgreSQL, I am trying to insert html code into my data base some text just cant be inserted such as single quotes for an example. I am looking for a code that would help me "trim" or allow allow my characters to be inserted. I have tried the following code it didnt work.

```
$title= $_POST['title'];
    $intro= $_POST['intro'];
    $content= $_POST['content'];
    $category= $_POST['category'];
    $sort_footer = 24;
 //insert code
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO content(title, intro, content, category, sort_footer ) 
    VALUES ( :title, :intro , :content , :category ,:sort_footer ) ");

    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':intro', $intro);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sort_footer', $sort_footer);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `it didnt work`? Did you get an error message?

Comment: after this line of code "$stmt->execute();" i check if the value of this variable  $stmt is true and it returns true yet id didn't insert in my database

Comment: correction , the value of $stmt is false after executing